# ¿Cómo pasar el valor de una variable de JQuery/Javascript a una de php?

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, laravel, laravel-5

Tengo el siguiente código:

```
        for(j=0; j< cmt_titulo.length; j++)
        {
            <?php $var='<script type="text/javascript">document.writeln(cmt_no[j]);</script>'; ?>
                fila='<p>' + cmt_titulo[j] + '</p>' + '<a href="' + {{URL::action('ComentarioController@entrarHilo', $var)}} + '"><button type="button">Entrar en hilo</button></a>';

            $("#resenias").append(fila);
        }
```

Me sale el siguiente error:
[image: unexpected token ':']

Cuando le doy a Learn More me manda a la siguiente localización:

[SyntaxError: missing ; before statement](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Errors/Missing_semicolon_before_statement)

Y en el debugger tengo el siguiente código interpretado:

```
        for(j=0; j< cmt_titulo.length; j++)
        {
                                fila='<p>' + cmt_titulo[j] + '</p>' + '<a href="' + http://localhost:8000/cliente/entrarHilo/%3Cscript%20type=%22text/javascript%22%3Edocument.writeln%28cmt_no%5Bj%5D%29;%3C/script%3E+ '"><button type="button">Entrar en hilo</button></a>';

            $("#resenias").append(fila);
        }
```

Si es por un ";" no lo veo, aunque yo creo que tiene más que ver con la conversión de datos...

Comment: ¿Asumo que el código que muestras es de un template de blade?

Comment: Exacto, eso es, me da un error raro en el que me dice que hay un ":" o algo así

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Esta es una pregunta típica cuando usamos Laravel (blade) y JS, y se puede solucionar de varias formas, pero básicamente tendrás que hacer el manejo del valor de la variable en JS, pues todo lo que sea PHP será 'renderizado' antes de JS y no podrás obtener el valor de `cmt_no[j]` si no has ejecutado JS antes (imposible técnicamente).

Lo que suelo hacer es un caso de estos es almacenar la variable de JS de alguna forma y utilizar un valor genérico en la url de Laravel, el cual voy a reemplazar al momento de llamar la URL por mi variable de JS.

A continuación te doy una idea rápida, aunque pueden haber errores (hace mucho tiempo no uso jQuery, lo abandoné por Vue):

```
    for(j=0; j< cmt_titulo.length; j++)
    {
        fila='<p>' + cmt_titulo[j] + '</p>' + '<a href="' + "{{URL::action('ComentarioController@entrarHilo','URL_PARAM') }}" + '" data-myvar="cmt_no[j]" class="button-go"><button type="button">Entrar en hilo</button></a>';

        $("#resenias").append(fila);
    }
```

Al almacenar el valor que quieres pasar a PHP en `data-mivar`, lo podemos leer con el evento click y reemplazar nuestro valor genérico en la URL, algo así:

```
$('.button-go').click(function (e) {
    e.preventDefault()

    // obtener variable del atributo data
    let myParam = $(this).data('myvar')

    // reemplazar valor genérico en la url por la variable
    $(this).attr('href').replace('URL_PARAM', myParam)

    // activar el clic de nuevo
    $(this).trigger('click')
});
```

Comment: Aunque el error era porque me recogía los ":" del http como que era código al interpretarlo el navegador (así que hardcodeé la ruta) tu respuesta me ha hecho ver una manera que no sabía de hacer las cosas, gracias.